# Phone gap integration in iOS

Tags: iphone, cordova, integration

i have developed iphone application almost, but for some screen i need to use already made functionality in java scripting, so i thought of using Phone gap, will it be possible to add this in already present project .

suggest me with your expert answers
thank you .

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible to integrate phonegap with native app.

My suggestion if you just need to use javascript, html and css in your native app why are you looking for Phonegap ? Use [**UIWebView**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

Comment: i have codingfor calculator will it work in uiweb view , i think web view for static images

Comment: UIImageView is for static images, WebView is something like a minified browser control

Comment: is it possible to add phone gap feature in alredy existing app, please answer for this problem thank you

Comment: @Youaregreat: No, integrating phonegap to already existing project is very difficult. Also you can't use objective c code in phonegap application